# Is there a way to encode any number into a series of 8-bit numbers, including a terminating character?

Tags: math, encoding, bit-manipulation, byte

So I would like to encode numbers as small as 0 and as high as very high (32-bit, 64-bit, other 8-bit multiples...). The simple approach is to just use the computer architecture's built-in support for "word" size or whatever, so like 32-bit or 64-bit are the common cases, so integers limited to that size. But I would like to do a theoretical thing and see if there is a way to encode *arbitrarily large* numbers using a sequence of 8-bit numbers.

But then as a caveat, I want to know when we've reached the end of **a number** in a stream of bytes. So you might have this stream of bytes:

```
nbbbbbbbbbbbbnnnnnbbbnnbnnnnnnnnnbbbbbbbnnbnnbb
```

...where `n` is the number and `b` is an arbitrary byte (this drawing isn't quite accurate to what I'm saying. `n` would be fairly few in sequence, while `b` would be relatively much larger). And the thing is, *the `n` is the number of bytes `b` in front of it*. So this way you can do this:

1. Read the number by combining the sequences of `n` somehow.
2. Skip that number of bytes to reach the next sequence of `n`.
3. Repeat.

The question is two parts:

1. How do you compute the number out of a sequence of 8-bit integers?
2. Such that, you also know when you've reached the end of the "number" encoding and are now at the "arbitrary byte" encoding section. Somehow you need to *reserve* some key numbers or bits to flag when you've reached the end of a number encoding, but I haven't figured this out.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Reserving a bit to indicate the end is how VLQ works, so that idea is indeed correct and in use. There are other schemes too. What have you not figured out?

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly it! I didn't know it was actually a _thing_. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't say how to actually combine the integers into a whole?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/exercism/javascript/tree/master/exercises/variable-length-quantity) isn't quite robust enough for my liking.

Comment: What do you want as output, a `BigInt`?

Comment: Yes a BigInt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSB-first VLQ could be decoded into a BigInt like this:

```
function decode(bytes, index) {
    index |= 0;
    var value = 0n;
    var t;
    do {
        t = bytes[index++];
        value = (value << 7n) | BigInt(t & 0x7F);
    } while (t >= 0x80);
    return { value: value, index: index };
}
```

The "end" position is also returned. It's really the position of the next thing in the data.